# Is the white hemolymph that comes out of a lobster (when boiling) edible?

Tags: food-safety, seafood, lobster

I know most parts of a lobster are edible except for what was afore mentioned in your content. But there is no mention of the hemolymph, the white substance that comes out of a fresh, live lobster when boiled. I was thinking about blending it into a bisque for intensifying the flavor.

Comment: What does "afore mentioned in your content" directly relate to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I'm sure I have eaten some, on multiple occasions. Frankly there aren't many animal parts that we can't digest.

Comment: Pufferfish liver :P

Comment: Pufferfish liver can be digested, once. But I'm really saying the hemolymph doesn't all escape the lobster, plenty seems to stick to the meat.

Comment: Haha I knew that response was coming :)